# elixir Logger for lists, tuples, etc

Tags: logging, elixir

I can use the elixir logger for inspecting strings

```
 > str = "string"
 > Logger.info "Here is a #{str}"
 [info] Here is a string
```

But when I log a list, it doesn't look pretty

```
 > list = [1,2,3,4,5]
 > Logger.info "Here is a list: #{list}"
 [info] Here is a list: ^A^B^C^D^E^F
```

When I log keyword list, it errors

```
 > kwl = [a: "apple", b: "banana"]
 > Logger.info "Here is a keyword list: #{kwl}"
   ** (ArgumentError) argument error
   (stdlib) :unicode.characters_to_binary([a: "apple", b: "banana"])
   (elixir) lib/list.ex:555: List.to_string/1
```

How do you logger lists, tuples and data types other than strings in Elixir?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Your best bet is to use `Logger.info "Here is some thing: #{inspect thing}"`. This way even if `thing` doesn't implement the `String.Chars` protocol, you still get something useful.

Comment: If you want to show a data structure, then inspect is definitely the way to go. to_string is more restricted by design. :)

Answer (score 2):

If the goal is to temporarily print something to the console instead of explicitly "logging" it, you can directly use [`IO.inspect/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/IO.html#inspect/2), instead of using [`inspect/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#inspect/2) in a `Logger` argument.

```elixir
IO.inspect(params)
```

It pretty-prints by default and since it returns back the input, you can pipe it in an existing chain with a label, which is very helpful when debugging:

```elixir
result =
  numbers
  |> IO.inspect(label: "Input list")
  |> Enum.filter(& rem(&1, 3) == 0)
  |> IO.inspect(label: "Filtered to multiples of 3")
  |> Enum.map(& &1 * &1)
  |> IO.inspect(label: "Numbers Squared")
  |> Enum.sum()
```