# How to Log something in Controller when Phoenix Server is running?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to print some debug information from one of my Controllers in my Phoenix app when the server is running.

```ex
defmodule PhoenixApp.TopicController do
  use PhoenixApp.Web, :controller

  def index(conn, _params) do
    log("this text")

    # ... 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Okay, turns out it's pretty straight forward. You need to require the `Logger` elixir module in your controller and call one of it's methods to log your text.

```elixir
defmodule PhoenixApp.TopicController do
    require Logger

    def index(conn, params) do
        Logger.info  "Logging this text!"
        Logger.debug "Var value: #{inspect(params)}"

        # ...
    end
end
```

Supported levels are:

- `:debug` - for debug-related messages
- `:info` - for information of any kind
- `:warn` - for warnings
- `:error` - for errors

---

*Source: [Elixir - Logger Documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/logger/Logger.html)*

Comment: If you want to inspect something within your log, you can `Logger.debug "debugging #{inspect thing}"` where `thing` is the object you want outputted (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28951208/elixir-logger-for-lists-tuples-etc)

Answer (score 14):

You can also just do `IO.puts` or `IO.inspect` and it'll show up, but IO.puts can be troublesome if what you're trying to print doesn't implement the String.Chars protocol